# Timer Array Tick Events or Suitable Alternative?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, events, timer

in VB I am trying to make a series of objects (VB powerpacks lineshapes) in an array show

```
lines(n).visible = true
```

for 400ms and then hide

```
lines(n).visible = false
```

To do this, I thought I would have a respective array of timers, and start them when the lines show. Then, when each of them tick (which happens after 400ms), the respective line hides and its timer is stopped and reset. However, when I tried to use the tick event on a specific object in the array, it didn't recognise the timer.

Comment: *...to use the tick event on a specific object in the array, it didn't recognise the timer*. What do you mean?? Show some relevant code please.

Comment: we cant *possibly* tell you what is wrong with the code *not* shown. see [Ask]

Comment: 1 timer, not an array of them

Comment: Depending on the timer or on how you're coding things, imagine your computer hangs a little like when you're launching a huge application... your Timer will fire not one event, but as many events as the hanging delay divided by the Interval, all in a row...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of an array of timers, it might be better to use one timer and an array of starting times, one for each line. In the click event, change true to false for each line that's been visible 400 milliseconds. Remember to restart the timer in the handler.